# How do you say "Count me in" or "I'm up for that!"?

Tags: phrase-requests

...or some similar enthusiastic reaction to a proposal of an activity or an event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mi opinias, ke frazoj kun „aliĝi” esprimas tiun ideon. Ekzemple:

-Mi aliĝas!

-Notu mian aliĝon!

Answer (score 2):

I want to take part = Mi volas partopreni.

Answer (score 2):

"Jes, volonte!"
"Ankaŭ mi!"
"Ne sen mi!"